# Firefox Extension/Addon Binary Component Backward Compatibility

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, components, backwards-compatibility

I have been reading up and looking at ways to compile binary components for Firefox extensions. Since Firefox 5 is being released (and 6 & 7 coming up soon) I was wondering if binary components are worth making anymore or just use a standalone executable to run the functionality I want.

I got a sample binary component to compile for Firefox 5 but when I tested it on Firefox 3.6, I get this error:

```
[Exception... "Could not convert Native argument arg 0 [nsISupports.QueryInterface]" nsresult: "0x8057000a (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_NATIVE)"
```

Running this code

```
var obj = Components.classes['@example.com/MyComponent;1'].QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.IMyComponent);
```

And errors at the QueryInterface. Apparently building for Firefox 4 (XULrunner-sdk 2.0 instead of 5.0 will work).

Here is the module code:

```
#include "mozilla/ModuleUtils.h"
#include "MyComponent.h"

NS_GENERIC_FACTORY_CONSTRUCTOR(MyComponent)

NS_DEFINE_NAMED_CID(MY_COMPONENT_CID);

static const mozilla::Module::CIDEntry kMyComponentCIDs[] = {
    { &kMY_COMPONENT_CID, false, NULL, MyComponentConstructor },
    { NULL }
};

static const mozilla::Module::ContractIDEntry kMyComponentContracts[] = {
    { MY_COMPONENT_CONTRACTID, &kMY_COMPONENT_CID },
    { NULL }
};

static const mozilla::Module kMyComponentModule = {
    mozilla::Module::kVersion,
    kMyComponentCIDs,
    kMyComponentContracts,
    NULL
};

NSMODULE_DEFN(NS_MyComponent_Module) = &kMyComponentModule;
NS_IMPL_MOZILLA192_NSGETMODULE(&kMyComponentModule)
```

I also heard that FF3.6 doesn't need to have the xpt or the dll inside the manifest file.

So basically my question is, for backward compatibility would it be better to make an executable or continue to make binary components? (Since it looks like compiling for FF5, FF3.6 broke.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message should be due to the XPT file not being recognized correctly (`Components.interfaces.IMyComponent` is `undefined`). Maybe that's because it is in the wrong directory - in Firefox 3.6 you don't declare it in the `chrome.manifest` file, instead it has to be located in the `compoments/` directory along with your dll file.

The backwards compatibility story of XPCOM components got a lot worse starting with Firefox 4, see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Interface_Compatibility#Binary_Interfaces. Theoretically, if you want to support multiple Firefox versions you need to put multiple versions of your XPCOM component into your XPI package, that's lots of effort for releases that come out every six weeks. If the point is really calling a few functions from a native library then you should seriously consider switching to [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes). You can also ship a native library (plain, not XPCOM) with your extension and use js-ctypes to call it. Firefox supports js-ctypes starting with version 4 (Gecko 2.0), for Firefox 3.6 you would still need a different solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into js-ctypes. Do you know if there will be an impact performance time using this method instead of binary components? Time to learn dll compiling, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user654628: No, I don't know - but if it is only a few calls then it shouldn't be worth thinking about. In general, XPCOM calls have significant overhead, especially when calling from JavaScript. So I am not even sure that js-ctypes is slower.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I posted a question along these lines here: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1318/how-to-access-your-own-shared-library-packaged-with-the-addon/  Can you perhaps reply there (or i can repost here) regarding how you might get access to a customer shared library .dll when you're trying to package it in an addon that was build with the addon sdk? In other words, I'm using javascript ctypes, but I still need to package my dll and load it into the addon somehow

Comment: @Derek: That's not a trivial question unfortunately. Add-on SDK doesn't support unpacked extensions, yet DLLs cannot work from a ZIP archive. So your extension would likely have to put the DLL into its `data` directory, then download it via binary XMLHttpRequest and write it to some temporary directory. And then you would be able to use it via js-ctypes. Figuring out the details of it will take quite a bit of time, time that I don't have right now.

Comment: Ah ok - well thanks for giving me a hint on how it might have been done. I had exhausted all the "trivial" ways of doing it. Is it still possible to make extensions without using the add-on sdk, or is there some "magic" going on that is going to make the old way deprecated in the near future.

Comment: @Derek: No, you can fairly easily create a [restartless extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) of your own (cleaner than classic extensions but sadly the majority of the documentation still applies to those). You have to make extra sure however that you close the library, otherwise it will be locked on update under Windows and cause issues.